# Change background colour of whole div on hover

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="index-card" data-card-index="5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center card-symbol">
            ה
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><i>He</i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <i>H</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS rule:

```
.index-card :hover {
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

Yet when I hover over empty space in the `.index-card` div, nothing happens. When I hover over individual child divs, such as `.card-symbol`, then only the background colour of that inner div changes.

How do I make the whole background of the `.index-card` div change colour on hover? Also, why does the whole div not change colour? The CSS rule is not for the inner divs but for the whole outer div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space after the class in the CSS, this causes any child elements to have the property applied instead. Remove the space, remove the issue

```css
.index-card {
  background: white;
}

.index-card:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-card" data-card-index="5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center card-symbol">
            ה
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><i>He</i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <i>H</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.my-card {
  background-color: white;
}

.my-card:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

if you want transition so you can use it `transition: 0.5s;`

```
.my-card {
   background-color: white;
   transition: 0.5s;
}
.my-card:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```